# Change aptana studio terminal tab title

Tags: aptana-studio

In aptana studio, we can create several terminal tabs like in below pic. It is difficult to recognize to know the tab as they all have same name.
[image]

Can we change the title of those terminal tabs of aptana as we can do in normal terminal tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on both terminal and aptana studio terminal tab.

```
echo -en "\033]0;New terminal title\a"
```